# react-native-router-flux - trigger function on specific route load

Tags: react-native

I am trying to trigger a function whenever a specific route within a router loads. I am using react-native-router-flux 2.x and ReactNative 0.21 (Can't update to 3.x right now).

For example below I just want to trigger a function whenever screen2 is loaded. Is this possible? I tried using onPush but it didn't seem to work.

The reason I need this is because I cannot use componentDidMount, componentWillMount for the screen2 component as it will only load the first time the component is called. I need a function to trigger every time the route is selected. Thanks!

```
  <Route name="screen1" initial={!needSignIn}>
    <Router footer={TabBar} hideNavBar={true} >
      <Route name="screen1" hideNavBar={true} title="Screen1" schema="tab" component={Screen1} />
      <Route onPush={()=>{console.log("onPush is called!");}} name="screen2" hideNavBar={true} title="Screen2" schema="tab" component={Screen2} />
      <Route name="screen3" hideNavBar={true} title="Screen2" schema="tab" component={Screen3} />
    </Router>
  </Route>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only events that can fire events with react-native-router-flux are onLeft and onRight [see documentation](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux#scene). The only to fire off functions are lifecycle functions. You said that component(Did/Will)Mount wont work, what about the others, like componentWillReceiveProps? Use componentWillMount for the first render, and componentWillReceiveProps for every other render.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, onLeft and onRight unfortunately won't help as the route I am triggering is a tab on a tab bar. Lifecycle functions are a good idea, however I notice that componentWillReceiveProps and componentDidUpdate, fire when I move away from the route in question, on an `AFTER_ROUTER_FOCUS` action? There doesn't seem to be a lifecycle function that I can hook into when I click on the tab?

Comment: what type of work do you need to do in your function? if its something like an api call, you could do the call first before you switch to the other route and then pass it as props.

Comment: if you cant do that then look at the [default actions fired from the router](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/src/Actions.js)

Comment: I need to clear out some state based on a condition, if an account connection to an API has been lost basically. If that state is not handled properly it will cause issues. I could poll periodically and check the connection but it seems overkill

Comment: I looked at using BEFORE_ROUTE and matching to a route name. However I can only react to this at the reducer level. I need this to happen at the component level so I can pass data to the reducer via an Action, if that makes sense

Comment: can you do this work before you go to this new route?

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. Turns out your first answer was correct. I added some code to check the current route using componentDidUpdate and checking the route in state. I took this (below) from the react-native-router-flux docs and modified it to my app. It fires every time I select the tab, and more importantly runs only once!

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const prevRoute = prevProps.global.currentRoute
    const currentRoute = this.props.global.currentRoute
    if (currentRoute === 'payment' && prevRoute !== currentRoute) {
      this.props.actions.doSomething()
    }
  }